# Make LibreOffice A single button that when clicked offers choices and what type of document to open

Tags: libreoffice, dock, button

I know that I've done this on a previous install of Ubuntu, but for the life of me, I can't find it. Basically I want the options like when you right click LibreOffice Writer and the New Document option appears. I'd just like them all combined so that there is New Spreadsheet, New Presentation etc. Appreciate any help in this matter.

-I'd like there to be a single LibreOffice button on the left hand side dock(Where it is off a fresh install with the three different colored LibreOffice buttons).
-Then once I left click it, it will boot up LibreOffice Writer but if I right click it, it gives me the option of what file type I'd like to open(Similar too the new Document or New spreadsheet that appears now. Just all in one.).

I would just get rid of it and only deal with it through the terminal but I share the computer with my younger brother. This means that my uncluttering needs to be done so that it still allows him easy access.

Comment: You probably saw [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/36375/12864) about making a LibreOffice 'custom quicklist'. Try that and see if it is what you want.

Comment: The custom quicklist that Tom provided was exactly what I've been looking for. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In terminal type `libreoffice` brings up where you can choose what to open.
Its also in your under office in your application menu.