# Commands for quicklists

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists, ubuntu-tweak

I am using Unity. The Quicklists feature is really useful. I added some entries in the nautilus quicklist from Ubuntu Tweak. Those commands were easy to figure out. 
But now i do not know how to find the commands that should be used to add a quicklist.
Every app has different way of a command.

For example:

While nautilus commands are like- `nautilus /home/username/Music`.
Chrome commands are completely different. like this- `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

Now how do i figure out them for applications which do not have any by default?

Comment: Sorry could you give an example of some of the specific things you want to do?  your nautilus example has nautilus open a specific folder, whereas the chrome example is just the path to the chrome application itself.  Do you want to know the locations of various applications (most are stored in `/usr/bin/`, chrome is kind of an exception), or the extra functionality you can add in with a command switch (like opening a specific folder or webpage automatically)?

Comment: Yes i would like to do that...And alos,in software center have update manager,etc.Or in Nitro have direct entries for add a task etc...BTW i found this too-http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available...But i would still like to know how to find the commands

Comment: @Alvar...Thanx...I have to rite the question inthat manner many times coz with the size being small,i always get the error "It does not match quality standards"

Comment: @Nirmik You get that error bcoz you indeed aren't typing the question properly i.e too many "!" or "?" or no proper full stops, line-breaks etc...

Answer (score 2):

it is very easy

```
[NewIncognito Shortcut Group]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --incognito
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

#### you must add a line like this

`X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=XXXXX;XXXXX;XXXXX` here `XXXXX` is name in `[ ]` except `Shortcut Group`

now for example,

you can give any name in between `[ ]` like here is `NewIncognito Shortcut Group`. but you must write `Shortcut Group` after name. it means that you can give any name in `[NewIncognito Shortcut Group]` in place of `NewIncognito` only.

`Name=` Can be anything but meaningful to know what it does.

`Exec=` is path to that executable(only if the directory is not in `PATH` variable) file like `Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

now the actual thing which is main thing for all this fuzz is parameter passed while opening the executable. here it is `--incognito`.

You always know which executable you want to start but your main problem is

#### Which parameter to use? or how do I know to use this one or that one?

just open terminal `cd`(no need to `cd` to dir if it's in your `PATH` variable) to directory where your executable is located.

now write name of your executable file(here is `google-chrome`) and then write `--help`. so You would type

`google-chrome --help`

this will show you different options or parameters which can be passed and other info about them. here is output

```
OPTIONS
       Google  Chrome has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are
       added and removed at the whim of the  developers.   Here,  we  document
       relatively stable flags.

   --user-data-dir=DIR
          Specifies  the directory that user data (your "profile") is kept
          in.  Defaults to ~/.config/google-chrome .   Separate  instances
          of  Google  Chrome  must  use  separate  user  data directories;
          repeated invocations of google-chrome  will  reuse  an  existing
          process for a given user data directory.

   --app=URL
          Runs URL in "app mode": with no browser toolbars.

   --incognito
          Open in incognito mode.

   --version
          Show version information.
```

this output is very long and i should not paste all here.

`google-chrome --help` opens `manpage` actually. but most of the time only text output  is given in terminal.

lets take example of banshee

if you run `banshee --help` it give something like

```
Usage: banshee [options...] [files|URIs...]

Help Options

  --help                   Show this help
  --help-playback          Show options for controlling playback
  --help-query-track       Show options for querying the playing track
  --help-query-player      Show options for querying the playing engine
  --help-ui                Show options for the user interface
  --help-debug             Show options for developers and debugging
  --help-all               Show all option groups
  --version                Show version information
```

they have divided help category wise. Now I want to know options for playback so I will type

```
banshee --help-playback
```

which shows,

```
Playback Control Options

  --next                     Play the next track, optionally restarting if the
                             'restart' value is set

  --previous                 Play the previous track, optionally restarting if
                             the 'restart value is set

  --restart-or-previous      If the current song has been played longer than 4
                             seconds then restart it, otherwise the same as
                             --previous

  --play-enqueued            Automatically start playing any tracks enqueued on
                             the command line

  --play                     Start playback
  --pause                    Pause playback
  --toggle-playing           Toggle playback
  --stop                     Completely stop playback
  --stop-when-finished       Enable or disable playback stopping after the
                             currently playing track (value should be either
                             'true' or 'false')

  --set-volume=LEVEL         Set the playback volume (0-100), prefix with +/-
                             for relative values

  --set-position=POS         Seek to a specific point (seconds, float)
  --set-rating=RATING        Set the currently played track's rating (0 to 5)
```

Now you know how to make it play next or previous or pause.
So you can create entries like

`Exec=banshee --next` for next song

`Exec=banshee --pause` to pause song

`Exec=banshee --previous` to Play the previous track

Comment: okay m trying all that you told but can you tell me will this-http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available work in precise?? I tried te terminal and software center one but it dint work...

Comment: @Nirmik though I don't use precise, it supposed to work.

Comment: @virpara...The ones with comletely new desktop entries worked...but  the ones with only quicklists additon dint...and in chrome etc,i wanted to add new tab and history and stuff like that which i do not get in the above method u mentioned...

Comment: @Nirmik quicklist is idea to start app with different parameters which it have. I could not figure out how to tweak for `new tab` and `history`.

Comment: @Nirmik I'll try to solve that give me time. already got two other projects to do and exam. I'm keeping everything noted. thanks to tomboy.

Comment: @virpara....ting ting! any help yet? :p

Answer (score 0):

Most applications are either stored in the directory `/usr/bin/` or have a link in that directory to where they are stored. Graphically you can navigate to the directory with Nautilus (the default file browser) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for the application name.  Hope this helps.