# Creating Quicklist for Tomboy Notes

Tags: tomboy, quicklists

I tried to create a tomboy quicklist for Unity by copying the tomboy.desktop
using the guide here
[What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)

using the man page for Tomboy it says you can open tomboy using 
**tomboy  --open-note [title/url]**

This works well when the application is closed. But once it has been opened, the command just display the window with the list of notes. 
When the command is run from the terminal it says
[ERROR 14:33:43.474] Tomboy is already running.  Exiting...

Zim Desktop Wiki on the hand recognised if the application is running and switched to that notebook.

With Tomboy I haven't been able too. I was hoping someone would know of a solution.

snippet from the .Desktop file

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Daily;
[Daily Shortcut Group]
Name=Daily
Exec= tomboy --open-note Daily
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried gnote (similar application to  Tomboy) and it is able to ideally handle the **gnote --open-note=Daily** command hence allowing you to create useful quicklists.

So I will most likely transfer my notes to that.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, a bug in Tomboy prevents it from being run with a different flag from command line if it is already started. Because of that, creating a quicklist for Tomboy is not really ideal because it won't work as intended.

I had been trying to create a quicklist for Tomboy some couple of months back and was blocked by this bug. I have since then filed a bug report on GNOME bugzilla and hopefully, the Tomboy developers will fix this shortly.

Here's the bug report:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674333

You can subscribe to the bug report and follow the progress of the bug.

Comment: I had already a bug on Launchpad, here is the link if you want to subscribe to it.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/1012970

Comment: The other method to do this could be through dbus and python. Docky has a helper for Tomboy, and there it has a script
/usr/share/dockmanager/scripts/tomboy_menus.py
but the script only works if Tomboy is running. 

This would mean a complex two prong approach would be needed.

I tried to add a comment to bugzilla but it crashed - Database server has hardware problems.. working on it, but will take a while

Comment: @pt123 Thanks for the bug link. I filed the bug upstream for better exposure. I didn't know about that docky script. Interesting idea. Let me know if you can comment on that Bugzilla link. Thanks.

Comment: I have asked a similar question for Chromium browser http://askubuntu.com/questions/150705/open-url-in-chromium-and-switching-to-existing-tab-open-if-url-already-open

this would be so useful in turning Gmail, Google Reader etc into actual Apps in Unity

Comment: I have added my comment on bugzilla. If you can confirm the Launchpad bug, maybe a Canonical employee might look into it as it affects Unity

Comment: @pt123 Confirmed the bug and linked to the upstream bug.