# How do I drag and drop a file from Nautilus into a minimized window icon on the Unity taskbar?

Tags: unity

For example: In GNOME-Shell I can drag a file from Nautilus to the upper left part of the screen, all windows (open and minimized) display on the screen, and then I can drop the file in one of the windows. In Unity is this a bug or just a missing feature?

Comment: As far as Unity is concerned , Drag and drop is already available in Unity , or rather whenever you launch something you can add it as launcher by right click menu on it. You can further refer this excellent Wikipedia on this matter here http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available

Comment: I know drag and drop is available, but not in the same way possible as in Gnome-Shell/KDE/Xfce from what I can tell. What I'm trying to do is drag something from nautilus into an minimized application icon, have that window open up as I drag the file over it, and drop it into that window.

Comment: Like dragging pdf file to minimized chrome , it works too.

Comment: I tried dragging files from the Nautilus window to the Unity taskbar, hovered over the minimized application icon for a few seconds, nothing happened. It seems from my end that the Unity taskbar is a launcher only. I can record a video clip if that would help.

Comment: For particular file to be opened you will have to drag their supported files. Are you using Unity 2D or 3D, and also Ubuntu 12.04 or previous version, because it works in Ubuntu 12.04 Unity 3D.

Comment: If it will help I can include a video link of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm trying to drag a .js file to sublime_text icon, how can I specify their supported files in the .desktop file???

Comment: @opensas: Sounds like a good candidate for a new question post.

Answer (score 1):

While dragging the file, hold the "windows"-button, then press tab until the wanted window is selected on the sidebar, then release the "windows"-button. The wanted window will be restored to the screen; you can then simply drop your file.

Comment: That does make sense. Thanks for the reply. I don't currently use Unity but will keep that in mind if I decide to try it again.