# How do I change the launcher commands?

Tags: launcher, command-line, execute-command

I'd like to change the behaviour of the launcher, so that if I click on the firefox icon, it runs the command

```
$ optirun firefox
```

Does anyone know how to change it?

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you change it in the dash, you'll automatically change it in the launcher. So start "main menu" (that's `alacarte`) from the dash, navigate to Internet and then Firefox. There you can set a new Run-entry (replace `firefox %u` with `optirun firefox %u` - whatever optirun is).
You could also edit the launcher manually with `sudo vim /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` and change the `Exec` line.

Comment: `optirun` is the command that lets you use your Nvidia driver. Bumblebee should be installed.

Comment: This helped me, but the other part of the answer for me was there: https://superuser.com/questions/1332765/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-of-menus-tabs-and-other-user-interface-element

Answer (score 12):

--First copy the `firefox.desktop` to home by,

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

if not present then create a new one in the above last location.

--Then open it for editing

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

--Third , add the following code.

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Optirun;NewWindow;
[Optirun Shortcut Group]
Name=Optirun Firefox
Exec=optirun firefox
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox -new-window about:blank
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Now save the File, browse through `~/.local/share/applications`. From there drag the `firefox.desktop` to the launcher.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/42853/63025

Comment: Why copy the shortcut to the desktop when you can edit the one in `/usr/share/applications/`?

Comment: I wonder if a software update could overwrite the modified shortcut. Maybe it is safer to make a new one with your custom options.

Comment: Changing the one in /usr/share/applications will change it for all users. It may also not be possible if you don't have root access (sudo).