# How to force Octave to launch in GUI mode from the dock?

Tags: octave

I wonder how to execute "octave --force-gui" (3.8.1) in Ubuntu (14.04) from the graphical interface without having to go through the terminal?

(The default icon in the dock bar executes "octave" which is okay but because there is nowadays a nice GUI I want to work in it..!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to modify the dock. A similar question was asked here:

[How do I change the launcher commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160374/how-do-i-change-the-launcher-commands)

The answer is to modify the properties using the 'alacarte' menu editor. Find the GNU Octave entry in this editor and change the command to '/usr/bin/octave --force-gui' in the properties window. Thereafter tick off the box which asks the program to be run in the terminal. Voila!

Answer (score 6):

I launched octave using "/usr/bin/octave --force-gui". This started the gui and dropped an icon on the dock for the gui. I right clicked this new icon and locked it to the dock. Then unlocked the defult Octave icon.

Comment: This worked for me. Doesn't allow quit to work properly though. (Octave 4.2)