# How to permanently open browsers in firejail?

Tags: .desktop, browser, firejail

I've edited `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` in the past to use `firejail` when running `firefox`, but it seems like this was removed during an update.

How can I permanently open browsers in Firefox without needing to update .desktop files whenever they're updated?

### `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`

These files still exist, they're unchanged from when I created them months ago. The system just isn't picking them up for some reason, and seems to be prioritising the ones in `/usr/share/applications` instead.

Some of this is redacted due to extraneous content (language specs, etc).

#### `firefox.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=firejail firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Name[ar]=افتح نافذة جديدة
Exec=firefox -new-window

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=firefox -private-window
```

#### `brave-browser.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Brave Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
# Gnome and KDE 3 uses Comment.
Comment=Access the Internet
Exec=firejail /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=brave-browser
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=application/pdf;application/rdf+xml;application/rss+xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xhtml_xml;application/xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;image/webp;text/html;text/xml;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable --incognito
```

### `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`

They're identical to the ones in `~/.local/share/applications`.

I just added `firejail` to the front of the `Exec` command in each `.desktop` file. These commands work fine when manually executed in the terminal.

### Further debugging info

I think this may have started happening after I updated from Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I'm not sure, though.

I haven't changed anything besides updating system packages with `apt`. I'm not aware of anything that could've caused this problem.

I know when it's working, because when it is, I can only access the `~/Downloads` folder when uploading files in the browser. And if I'm running it from the command line, I'll get output from firejail.

Comment: Just make your own .desktop file and that one won't get updated when the application itself gets updated. You can add it to the various menus as needed, there are ample directions online for that. See [here for example](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-shortcuts-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to open Firefox in a Firejail sandboxed environment every time a web page is opened (by whichever means).
How to achieve this will vary depending on the method you use to start firefox:

1. Command line
2. A launcher in dash
3. A launcher in the desktop

For method 1 above, you can set an alias in your `~/.bashrc` (assuming you use bash)

```
alias firefox='firejail firefox'
```

For method 2 above, the option you posted in the question should work.
I suggest you repeat that, and if the change in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` you perform is ever reverted, you check the date of the change.
Then compare with e.g. `less /var/log/apt/history.log` what could have been the update that caused the change (sources: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history), [2](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/01/how-to-show-history-of-installed.html)).
You can actually try this in your current state.

You can also create your own `.desktop` as you mention in your answer.
Then drag it to the dash (I am not sure you did that).
Same as above, I suggest you repeat the operation, and check whenever this stops working for the possible cause.

---

**EDIT**

In addition, I suggest you post the following detailed information:

1. The commands you use to verify when "it is working" and "when it is not", and the output that shows it. It is better if you copy this verbatim (instead of "explaining" what you did).
2. The location and full contents of your `.desktop` files, after you changed them, and after the system changed them.

You did not specify:

1. In your question, what action you performed that reverted your changes in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`. "An update" is quite loose... did you update firefox, or some other application?
2. In your answer, what action you performed that made your `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` inoperative. "doesn't seem to have worked long-term" is again loose. Plus, is your `.desktop` file is still there and with its contents the same as when it worked, but now simply not working? Or was it somehow modified?

Getting your feedback on this will help a lot.

**Related**:

1. [How do I change the launcher commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160374/how-do-i-change-the-launcher-commands)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure what reverted the changes in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`. I've also tried `~/.local/share/applications` with no luck. I've had many updates of my browsers since then, and most of the time it worked. But then it randomly stopped working. IIRC there were times it worked, stopped working, and randomly started working again.

Comment: I still have the `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` for my browsers. They're intact. I'm going to try the `alias` anyway, that's a good idea so I don't need my own `.desktop` file.

Comment: Okay so I just tried adding the alias in `~/.zshrc`, that didn't work for the launcher/dash. I figured maybe that uses bash, so I put it in `~/.bashrc`, but that didn't work either. I then rebooted, that didn't work.

Comment: I also then tried editing the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` and making them run with firejail, but after rebooting, the `firejail` command was removed from `Exec`. So I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: @dspacejs - A few notes:
1) Please see EDIT.
2) As said in the answer, `alias` is not expected to help when launching from dash.
3) So rebooting reverts the changes you introduce in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`?

Comment: Thanks for your time and sorry for the delay getting back to you. I've just added all your requested details to my question.

Comment: @dspacejs - 1) You did not post the contents of `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`.
2) There are two `Exec` lines in `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` that you should also prepend with `firejail`, reboot and try again.

Comment: That worked—I was missing the two other `Exec` lines like you said. Not sure how I made this careless mistake lol. I only needed to update it in `~/.local/share/applications`. I don't know why it worked with the one `Exec` line in the past, though, something must have changed. Thanks.

Comment: @dspacejs - Glad that it worked. One more lesson, I guess... it is good to help others help you, by taking the time for being detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can copy the `.desktop` file from its original location into `~/.local/share/applications` and it will use this instead. During updates, your changes won't be overwritten.

**Update:** this doesn't seem to have worked long-term.

Answer (score -1):

As I know you haven't to do anything because:

```
$ which firefox
/usr/local/bin/firefox
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/firefox 
/usr/local/bin/firefox -> /usr/bin/firejail
```