# List of applications that support quicklists

Tags: 12.04, quicklists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)

I was wondering if there was a list of applications that support qicklists, and how to get them working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link [1]: http://maketecheasier.com/8-really-useful-ubuntu-unity-quicklists/2011/05/07

It gives you 8 useful quicklist.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.