# Is there a way to get a list of my favourite programs so I don't have to 'store' them in in my vertical dock??

Tags: launcher

That way I can have my running programs in the vertical dock not mixed in with my favourite programs.

I shouldn't have to write my favourite programs down on a piece of paper in order to avoid a cluttered vertical dock.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a  launcher, that had a right click QuickList Menu, that would display and launch all your favourite programs.

You can find examples of the `.desktop` entries you will need to make and a general idea  here [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)