# Custom Unity Quicklists not working after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, launcher, quicklists

In the popular question [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available) are listed a lot of launchers with custom quicklists for Unity, that worked for Ubuntu old release, included 12.04.

This is a sample from the first answer:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents

[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus Videos
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Why that quicklists are missing after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10? This code is no more supported?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the specifications of the .desktop files are changed, starting from Ubuntu 12.10, to be compliance with the [Freedesktop "Additional applications actions" standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s08.html).

This is how the change your old .desktop file:

- OLD: **X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=ENTRY1;ENTRY2...**
- NEW: **Actions=ENTRY1;ENTRY2...**

---

- OLD: **[ENTRY Shortcut Group]**
- NEW: **[Desktop Action ENTRY]**

---

- OLD: **TargetEnvironment=Unity**
- NEW: **OnlyShowIn=Unity;**

Taking the above example (in the question), it would be changed in this way to work in Ubuntu 12.10 and later:

```
Actions=Videos;Documents

[Desktop Action Videos]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus Videos
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Documents]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Here the link to the official reference of the Unity Launcher API:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Quicklists