# How can i edit the nautilus quicklist in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: nautilus, quicklists

in ubuntu 13.10 how can i edit the quicklist?
Because i need to add some other place and remove some that are default (like picture, video, etc)
thanks!

Comment: i knew it! but in 13.10 there's nothing into the nautilus*.desktop files

Comment: how about making a new on based on this http://askubuntu.com/a/39747/47291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that in newer Nautilus (note: the question is about Nautilus, not the Unity Launcher!) the File menu is almost impossible to find.

In gnome shell you have to click in the upper-panel "File" name to have the menu for Nautilus which is called File now:

[image: Nautilus preferences menu]

Now go to bookmark and edit them at your wish.