# The best LAMP Stack with a GUI for Web Dev

Tags: server, 13.10, apache2, mysql, lamp

I'm a spoilt windows user and always have used a WAMP stack with a GUI that allows me to start or stop apache and mysql services. I find it really hard switching to the LAMP command line and was wondering if any of you could share some information.

I have been using the bitnami linux install and with regard to stability, its absolutely horrid!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Best,

Comment: Many of us are willing to "help" or "share information". Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 3):

This is so easy. Using it in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it's working without a hitch:

[image]

1. Create a new file via terminal by running the command below

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/lamp.desktop
   ```
2. Copy and paste this text inside

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=LAMP
   GenericName=LAMP
   X-GNOME-FullName=LAMP
   Comment=Open services of your LAMP server
   Exec=gksu service apache2 start &amp;&amp; gksu service mysql start
   Icon=emblem-web
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true

   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Start;Stop;Restart

   [Start Shortcut Group]
   Name=Start
   Exec=gksu service apache2 start &amp;&amp; gksu service mysql start
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Stop Shortcut Group]
   Name=Stop
   Exec=gksu service apache2 stop &amp;&amp; gksu service mysql stop
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Restart Shortcut Group]
   Name=Restart
   Exec=gksu service apache2 restart &amp;&amp; gksu service mysql restart
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
3. Drag and Drop onto the launcher by navigating to `~/.local/share/applications/` in Nautilus.

**Source:** [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)

Answer (score 0):

We have two GUI's available

- To have MySQL GUI you can install and use phpmyadmin. To install

  ```
  sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
  ```

  With this you can manage MySQL database in GUI way.
- To have Apace GUI you can use rapache , with this tool you can manage both local & remote connections.

  ```
    sudo apt-get install rapache
  ```

Comment: Rapache is not available - `E: Unable to locate package rapache`

Comment: version of Ubuntu @Parto ?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, phpMyAdmin doesn't allow for the starting/stopping of the mysql service. The [MySQL Workbench app](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) is a GUI and does allow for remote MySQL Server administration, including starting and stopping the server and many other functions. I run it on my Ubuntu workstation for running queries, creating dbases and tables, user admin, and managing backups of mysql.

The command line is actually easy to use for starting and stopping services like Apache and mysql:

`sudo service apache stop` will stop the process.

`sudo service apache restart` will restart the service (loading any new configs).

`sudo service apache start` will start the service.

Replace `apache` with `mysql` in the command for the same functions.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with douggro as I am a fan of command line.  However, there is python-based app that I use it with so much benefit for my other purposes when using my server.  You could run this app right off your browser even if apache is not up.

Webmin

```
 wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.660_all.deb 
 sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.660_all.deb -y
```

Since you are using WAMP stack, this probably is beneficial for you as well -who knows.

Usermin

```
 wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/usermin_1.560_all.deb
 sudo dpkg -i usermin_1.560_all.deb -y
```

You can control MySQL and even more functions.  It has the feature where you are looking for in controlling with restarting feature.

Comment: Webmin provides everything Usermin does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xampp which works pretty much in the same way as wampp, it even has an installer!

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: How is this better than the other solutions?